# Refresh-token rotation without additional frontend requests

Tags: authentication, server, web-authentication

I'm implementing a refresh-token rotation mechanism. For the sake of simplicity in implementing the frontend I would like to remove the need for requesting a new access token when an old one expires.

The idea I have goes:

- User logs in via Email and password.
- The server generates a pair of tokens and sets them in the httpOnly cookies
- The user makes a request for a resource with an expired access token
- Server recognizes the expired access token and validates the refresh token

  - If the refresh token is valid

    - a new pair of tokens is generated and saved into the httpOnly cookies
    - the requested resource is returned to the user

Would this approach be sufficient for security?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Do you need SSO or similar functionality? Is it only auth you require or authorization too? Do you need to log out the user if needed from all devices at the same time?

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome.
I'm not planning on utilising SSO (at least at this moment). The system will use a permission-based access for each endpoint. Users are assigned roles, each role can have multiple permissions (CRUD for entities). At the time of login user id and permissions (array of strings) are signed and that becomes the access token. The logout from all devices feature is not needed

Comment: Ok. What if the expired token gets stolen, what about then?

Comment: The access tokens have a very short TTL, around 5 minutes. The refresh tokens have a longer life (around 1 day) but can't be reused when they expire/are used.

Comment: Your approach is no different from how access token is refreshed. The additional frontend request is required when the Oauth2 provider is a 3rd party but in your case your web server is the issuer. You can use this approach.